# Adding dynamically rows to xeditable using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to read my date from the database instead using the code below :

```
 app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope, $filter, $http) {
   $scope.users = [
     {id: 1, name: 'awesome user1', status: 2, group: 4, groupName: 'admin'},
     {id: 2, name: 'awesome user2', status: undefined, group: 3, groupName: 'vip'},
     {id: 3, name: 'awesome user3', status: 2, group: null}
  ];
 .
 .
 .
 });
```

I saw there is a solution to use $scope.array, but I don't know how.

This is the complete [EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/NfPcH/633/).

Answer (score 0):

I am using the rest service to get data from the server(from database).

In service.js file write a rest service as

```
services.factory('UserSearchFactory', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/rest/getAllUsers', {}, {
        search: { method: 'GET', isArray: true}
    })
});
```

Then in controller.js file call the service

```
$scope.users = UserSearchFactory.search();
```

The data will be retrieved from the database using the rest call. The data will be automatically set to the fields.

Everything is same as in the example.